# Evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^z}$ where $\Re(z)>\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I am dealing with the following complex integration:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^z} \quad\text{ where }\quad\Re(z)>\frac{1}{2}$$

But I do not know how exactly to deal with the $z$.

Comment: By exploiting symmetry and enforcing the substitution $x=\tan\theta$ you immediately get something manageable through Euler's Beta function.

Comment: @thdr Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Schwinger parametrization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger_parametrization) one can write
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^z}dx=\frac{1}{\Gamma(z)}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_0^\infty t^{z-1}e^{-t(1+x^2)}dtdx$$
Then switching the order of integration we have
$$\frac{1}{\Gamma(z)}\int_0^{\infty}t^{z-1}e^{-t}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-tx^2}dxdt$$
The second integral is a [Gaussian integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral) and can be found by using the substitution $s=\sqrt{t}x\rightarrow ds=\sqrt{t}dx$ which gives
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-tx^2}dx=\frac1{\sqrt{t}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-s^2}ds=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}t}$$
So the integral becomes
$$\frac{1}{\Gamma(z)}\int_0^{\infty}t^{z-1}e^{-t}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}t}dt=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\Gamma(z)}\int_0^{\infty}t^{z-1.5}e^{-t}dt$$
and then the integral left is the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) - $\Gamma(z-0.5)$ - because
$$\int_0^\infty t^{z-1}e^{-t}dt=\Gamma(z)$$
Giving the final answer of
$$\boxed{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^z}dx=\sqrt{\pi}\frac{\Gamma(z-0.5)}{\Gamma(z)}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(z)$ be given by

$$f(z) =\int_0^\infty \frac1{(1+x^2)^z}\,dx$$

Since the integrand is an even function of $x$ we have after enforcing the substitution $x\mapsto \sqrt x$

$$\begin{align}
f(z)&=\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{-1/2}}{(1+x)^z}\,dx\\\\
&=B(1/2,z-1/2)\\\\
&=\sqrt \pi \,\frac{\Gamma(z-1/2)}{\Gamma(z)}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.  And feel free to up vote and accept an answer as you see fit.