# How to evaluate $\int \frac{1}{(\sqrt{a^2+x^2})^p}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(\sqrt{a^2+x^2})^p}dx, \space (p>1)$$

I think it is not as simple as it seems.

I tried to let $x=\arctan\theta$ or $x^2=a^2t$, still it is so difficult for me.

I believe there exists a specific value because the integrand converges zero.

How to integrate this?

---

so, it's a specific constant, right? This is from my original question [The last step of proof of Converse mapping for Mellin Transform](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4769375/1042620) that no one care. Another 2 books also written like this. I think the book missed $t^{-1/2}$ in the integrand. Anyway, if it is a constant, I manage to understand it.

Comment: Note that the integrand is even. Integrate only on the positive axis. Take $x=at$. Use [the beta function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.12.E3).

Comment: *Mathematica*:  $$\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \Gamma \left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right) | a| ^{1-p}}{\Gamma
   \left(\frac{p}{2}\right)}$$

Comment: Checkt this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3159275/42969

Comment: so, it's a specific constant, right? This is from my original question
 https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4769375/1042620 that no one care.